# Auto-Run disabled? should i be concerned with this error?

Tags: rigging

i am just getting into rigging in blender, and in the graph editor with the properties panel open i get a error message saying "ERROR: Phyton auto-execution disabled." Another thing that i noticed is a message on the top menu bar saying "Auto-run disabled."

I am in the graph editor because i want to create a driver for a simple but convent 2d ball rig, and i was wondering will be a problem for me later down the road. Also, what the heck should i do about the message. I don't like "ERROR"  sign being thrown at me.

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: I just click on a sign that said revert to trusted, and i lost all of my current progress, sigh!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature of Blender that tries to prevent you from running (possibly) malicious code when opening a file.

Animation drivers are actually Python statements (if I recall correctly, there is a way to make them multiline), which normally serve to control l parameters in some advanced ways; rigs tend to have a few drivers, since it's just easier to make work properly that way. However, if someone wanted to, they could, for instance, delete all your files, capture and send private information like passwords, keys and tokens, possibly, without you even noticing.

If you open the file from within Blender, there is an option to mark a file as trusted and thus run all scripts inside. Use at your own risk.

Another option is, in the User Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>), to allow scripts, from all files, to run; if you don't save the user preferences, they'll only apply to the open file. You can also exclude some directories, if you want; if you do this, I recommend disabling it for your  "Downloads" folder. Again, use at your own risk :P

[image]

Comment: yeah but how does that relate to rigging or animation or any thing else beside malicious code. Besides, what purpose could malicious code serve to software like Blender

Comment: yeah this answers my question, but does this mean i am running  malicious code right now on my computer?

Comment: When i clicked "revert to trusted" why the heck did it destroy my current session in blender? as i was in the process of creating a rig.

Comment: I am currently doing the same process all over again, but ever since i click the revert to trusted button i am not getting the "ERROR" message any more, Why is that?

Comment: No, it is disabled to prevent that. If your creating your own drivers then, arguably, it should realise that you entered it and want it to run, but that would be a  "bug" which should be reported to the tracker. For bow the solution is to change the preferences as shown in the image, but to also exclude downloads, just in case.

Comment: Thar I do not know... It might be new or I just didn't notice it, but I've never seen such button